# How to handle refreshing an access token in a SvelteKit app?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

The backend API gives out a access/refresh token pair on login. The access token is short lived and the refresh token is long lived.

I was thinking about storing those tokens in a HttpOnly cookie.

Then it's easy enough to read it from a server hook (`hooks.server.ts`), and if the access token has expired, then request a new access/refresh token pair using the refresh token and override the previous cookies.

In a server side `load` function I'd then want to use the access token to request data from the API.

But the hook doesn't always run, like when client side navigation is happening, only on hard refresh.

So the access token could by expired and refreshed.

Guess I could have another refresh mechanism on the `load` as well, but I'm not sure.

Where are people storing the access/refresh token pairs and handling the refreshing when the access token has expired?

Comment: One possible way may be using "onNavigate", "beforeNavigate" or "afterNavigate" in "+layout.svelte". Actually, I haven't had any issue with the load function unless you are building without SSR. It almost always hits the load function.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a server side load on client-side navigation, I would really recommend on using [+page.server.js](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing#page-page-server-js). There, you can implement the `load` function that loads the data from server on client-side navigation.

In the load function, you can pass a `cookies` parameter which then you can use to set or get cookies on the server side.

```
export async function load({ cookies }) {
const sessionid = cookies.get('sessionid');

return {
    user: await db.getUser(sessionid)
  };
}
```